# Object Moved Here error

Tags: c#

I've developed a web service with Form based authentication as below.

1.An entry in web.config as below.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="Loginpage.aspx" name=".AuthAspx">
</forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>

<authentication mode="Forms">

<forms loginUrl="Loginpage.aspx" name=".AuthAspx"/></authentication>

<authorization><deny users="?"/> </authorization>
```

2.In Login Page user is validate on button click event as follows.

```
if (txtUserName.Text == "test" && txtPassword.Text == "test")

        {

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, // Ticket version

                txtUserName.Text,// Username to be associated with this ticket

                DateTime.Now, // Date/time ticket was issued

                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50), // Date and time the cookie will expire

                false, // if user has chcked rememebr me then create persistent cookie

                "", // store the user data, in this case roles of the user

                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath); // Cookie path specified in the web.config file in <Forms> tag if any.

            string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies); // Hashed ticket

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

            if (returnUrl == null) returnUrl = "~/Default.aspx";

            Response.Redirect(returnUrl, false);

        }
```

3.Webservice has a default webmethod.

[WebMethod]

```
    public string HelloWorld()

    {      

            return "Hello World";            

    }
```

4.From a webApplication I am making a call to webservice by creating proxy after adding the webreferance of the above webservice.

```
          localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();           


            service.Credentials = ystem.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;;


            string hello = service.HelloWorld();

            Response.Write(hello);
```

and here while consuming it in a web application the below exception is thrown from webservice proxy.

--
Object moved

### Object moved to here.

Comment: That's been IIS config or partial deployment problems for me before

Comment: Hi Tahbaza thanks for replying...not got what you mean by iis config?? when I change authentication from Forms to Windows it work fine  :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to specifically allow access to the login page or nobody can read it who isn't already logged in.

See [ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) - `<deny users="?"/>` denies all anonymous users.